# Angular 5 and material - How to change the background color from SnackBar component

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have to change the background from the snackbar component.
I'm using it to alert or inform the user about some either error or completed action the user did.

The material version from the project.
"@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc.1",

The documentation https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api say about an api to change the class.

panelClass: string | string[]
Extra CSS classes to be added to the snack bar container.

This is what I add in the css file.

```
.mycsssnackbartest {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

This is the code to open the snackbar

```
this.snackBar.open('Informing the user about sth', 'User Message' , {
    panelClass: ['mycsssnackbartest ']
} );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `MatSnackBarConfig` has a field named `extraClasses` "Extra CSS classes to be added to the snack bar container." You are using `panelClass` which it doesn't exists

Comment: If found panelClass in the api documentation. https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api. I didn't use extraClasses because the documentation says it is Deprecated. But I'm going to test it. Thanks.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

#### Angular < V15

You have to use the `panelClass` option (since v6) to apply classes on a snackbar like this:

```
this.snackBar.open(message, action, {
  duration: 2000,
  panelClass: ['blue-snackbar']
});
```

CSS (in global styles.scss):

```
.blue-snackbar {
  background: #2196F3;
}
```

See the [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stacb4)

#### Angular >= v15

The Angular team did add global css variable

So you still need to add the `panelClass` and you can add it to CSS like this

```scss
  .mat-mdc-snack-bar-container {
    &.blue-snackbar {
      --mdc-snackbar-container-color: #2196f3;
      --mat-mdc-snack-bar-button-color: #fff;
      --mdc-snackbar-supporting-text-color: #fff;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It worked. I wasn't using scss file. I was trying to set it in the css file from the component.

Comment: As of material 6 extraClasses has been deprecated.  panelClass should provide the same functionality.

Comment: @BrianStanley Thank you, I updated the example and my answer accordingly!

Comment: Doesn't work without !important for the background color.

Comment: I had to add !important to the css rule to make it work properly

Comment: This could be improved by using themes. See answer by @FranSanchis.

Comment: Only works with `::ng-deep` on my configuration (Angular 7.0.3).

Comment: add mat-toolbar in panelClass array and then no need to use ::ng-deep or important

 this.snackBar.open(message, action, {
      duration: 30000,
      panelClass: ['mat-toolbar', 'blue-snackbar']
    });

Comment: Man, thanks a lot! 

https://medium.com/cmind/custom-theme-for-angular-material-components-series-apply-theme-c12ce3bfa4a this article is complete BS

Comment: Works well in styles.scss. No need to deep or important in global.

Comment: Does anyone know how to get the global vars in >v15 to work with color palettes/themes? 
Using mat.get-color-from-palette does not seem to work in combination with the global vars

Comment: I have the same issue with mat.get-color-from-palette. If I am trying to color the back ground, it only works if I add both --mdc-snackbar-container-color and background-color styles to the class, both using mat.get-color-from-palette

Answer (score 66):

Using themes:

Primary:

```
this.snackBar.open('Some message','Some action', {
    duration: 2000,
    panelClass: ['mat-toolbar', 'mat-primary']
});
```

Switch: `'mat-primary'` to `'mat-accent'` or `'mat-warn'`

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer, as it does it properly by using themes.

Comment: @PurplePiranha I don't agree, `mat-toolbar` is another element of angular material and using this config changed the font size on my `mat-snackbar` which is not really intended. Can be useful in some cases though...

Comment: This is just a (in my opinion bad) workaround as it uses the class of a different element to style the snackbar. The OK button for example looks odd as it does not get affected by the styling with this approach. It would be better to make your own class and put it into global styles.scss (as suggested by the accepted answer)

Answer (score 22):

```
//in component.ts
this.snackbar.open(message, '', {
    duration: 2000,
    verticalPosition: 'top',
    panelClass: ['warning']
 });
//in component.css
::ng-deep .warning{
   background: 'yellow';
}
```

Comment: I'm using Angular 7 and this worked for me, not the accepted answer. You have to add ::ng-deep in front of the class name in your css. Thanks so much!

Comment: ::ng-deep is depreciated and will not be supported in the future by Angular https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

Comment: what should we use instead in this case ?

Comment: @An-droid, Angular has not set a version for the removal, since there is no replacement option yet (https://angular.io/guide/deprecations). But I would advise to use global styling (via styles.scss) in combination with the panelClass option for this instead of component specific styling

Comment: by doing so I'm forced to use `!important` which I shouldn't be using for that application TT.TT

Comment: By giving it a panel class you can give it more specific styling, thus overriding the material styling: `.mat-snack-bar-container.warning { background-color: red }`.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah after adding ::ng-deep in global style file(.css) works fine after each attribute... As follows

```
noMatchConfig: MatSnackBarConfig = {
    duration: 2000,
    horizontalPosition: 'right',
    verticalPosition: 'top',
    panelClass:['redNoMatch']
  }



::ng-deep .redNoMatch
{
  color:white;
  background: #F44336 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

complementing [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47569076/9027255): if you have CSS (not SASS) and ViewEncapsulation enabled, it looks like this:

```css
 ::ng-deep .mat-mdc-snack-bar-container.blue-snackbar {
    --mdc-snackbar-container-color: #2196f3;
    --mat-mdc-snack-bar-button-color: #fff;
    --mdc-snackbar-supporting-text-color: #fff;
  }
```

Comment: In my case worked without ::ng-deep, but you have to place it in global styles. (styles.scss)

Comment: thanks, but I prefere to keep styles isolated by components

Comment: only this worked for me

Comment: thanks for the tip ! worked perfectly for me Angular 16 CSS only

Answer (score 1):

This can also be achieved globally by importing `MAT_SNACK_BAR_DEFAULT_OPTIONS` in `app.module.ts`:

**app.module.ts**

```
import {
  MatSnackBarModule,
  MAT_SNACK_BAR_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MAT_SNACK_BAR_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
      useValue: { panelClass: ['mycsssnackbartest'] },
    },
  ],
})
```

**styles.css**

```
.mycsssnackbartest {
  background-color: blue;
}
```