# How to disable background in Angular snackbar?

Tags: angular, angular-material, snackbar

I want to disable background options while angular snackbar is being displayed. How to achieve this in angular 10?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 5 and material - How to change the background color from SnackBar component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47560696/angular-5-and-material-how-to-change-the-background-color-from-snackbar-compon)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47560696/angular-5-and-material-how-to-change-the-background-color-from-snackbar-compon) you have to add the `panelClass` property to your snackBar configuration and set it to the CSS class which defines the background color.

To achieve your goal I assume you have to set the background class of your panelClass to transparent doing

```css
.mycsssnackbartest {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```